# Write $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ as a disjoint union of two measurable subsets such that non of which contain a cylinder.

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the space $X=[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (with respect to the product topology). I'd like to think of $X$ as the set of all sequences with values in $[0,1]$.

My Question: Is it possible to split $X$ into a disjoint union of two measurable subsets $X=\mathcal{A}_1\sqcup\mathcal{A}_2$ such that no cylinder of $X$ lies in any of the $\mathcal{A}_i$?

By a cylinder I mean a set of all sequences whose values at some finitely many indices $n_1,...,n_k$ are fixed. (i.e. sets of the form $\{a_n\in X : a_{n_1}=b_1,...,a_{n_k}=b_k\}$ where $b_1,...,b_k\in[0,1]$ are given, for example the set of all the sequences which begin with $\frac{1}{2}$ is a cylinder).

Edit: It turns out I recieved a positive answer in which one of the sets $\mathcal{A}_1$ is of measure zero (with respect to the standard Borel measure on $X$). I wonder if one could generalize the given construction for the case where both $\mathcal{A}_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$ are of positive measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$A_1 = \{x: x_n = 0\ \text{eventually}\}$$
and $A_2$ its complement.

EDIT:
For an example with the additional requirement that both $A_i$ are of positive measure, let 
$ A_1 $ be the set of sequences $x$ such that there is an odd $n$ with $x_n < 2^{-n}$ but $x_j \ge 2^{-j}$ for all $j > n$, $A_2$ its complement.  Note that almost every $x$ has $x_n < 2^{-n}$ for only finitely many $n$.

Comment: Oh looks like I forgot an important assumption that I need $A_1,A_2$ to be of positive measure... I will wait to see if there are any results with the additional assumption. If not I'll just accept yours. Thanks for this answer too.

Comment: After the edit: Why is $A_1$ of positive measure? Even if you just take $x_j>2^{-j}$ for infinitely many $j$ you already get a set of measure zero. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are.  The measure of $x$ for which $x_j > 2^{-j}$ for all $j\ge 1$ is $\prod_{j=1}^\infty (1 - 2^{-j})$, an infinite product which converges to a nonzero limit.

Comment: Of course. I think it works now, is it necessary that $n$ is odd?

Comment: My example has the additional property that any set of positive measure depending on only finitely many coordinates has intersections of positive measure with $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_m,b_m \in [0,1]^{\mathbb N}$ be such that $a_m(n)=\delta_{m,n}$ and $b_m(n)=1-\delta_{m,n}=1-a_m(n)$. Then
$$
A_1 = \{x\in [0,1]^{\mathbb N}: x_0 \leq 1/2\} \cup \{b_m:m\in\mathbb N\} \setminus \{a_m:m\in\mathbb N\}
$$
and
$$
A_2 = \{x\in [0,1]^{\mathbb N}: x_0 > 1/2\} \cup \{a_m:m\in\mathbb N\} \setminus \{b_m:m\in\mathbb N\}
$$
should do the job.

Moreover the measures are $|A_1|=|A_2|=1/2$.

**Edit:** I had previously read $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ instead of $[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$. Now it is fixed.

Comment: Thank a lot. However this result doesn't help me much more than the original . One can change $A_1$ or $A_2$ by a set of measure zero and then it would contain a cylinder so this is not so much different than the previous answer. However you helped me discover that I need to think much better about how to formalize my question to avoid all sort of "measure zero counterexamples".

Comment: There is an easy fix for that. I'm adding it

Comment: No I was wrong, I cannot fix that. sorry :)

Comment: It's ok looks like Robert changed his answer and it looks right to me. Anyway your solution was interesting and I managed to learn from it. Thank you.

Comment: Yes I've read that. Very nice solution. Thank you for the problem :)